# antlr4 grammar string with number

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a problem with antlr4 grammar in java.

I would like to have a lexer value, that is able to parse all of the following inputs:

- Only letters
- Letters and numbers
- Only numbers

My code looks like this:

parser rule:

```
new_string: NEW_STRING+;
```

lexer rule:

```
NEW_DIGIT: [0-9]+;
STRING_CHAR : ~[;\r\n"'];
NEW_STRING: (NEW_DIGIT+ | STRING_CHAR+ | STRING_CHAR+ NEW_DIGIT+);
```

I know there must be an obvious solution, but I have been trying to find one, and I can't seem to figure out a way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first two lexer rules are not `fragment`s, they can (and will) be matched if the input contains just digits, or `~[;\r\n"']` (since if equally long sequence of input can be matched, first lexer rule wins).

In fact, `STRING_CHAR` can match anything that `NEW_STRING` can, so the latter will never be used.

You need to:

- make sure `STRING_CHAR` does not match digits
- make `NEW_DIGIT` and `STRING_CHAR` fragments
- check the asterisks - almost everything is allowed to repeat in your lexer, it doesn't make sense at first look ( but you need to adjust that according to your requirements that we do not know)

Like this:

```
fragment NEW_DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment STRING_CHAR : ~[;\r\n"'0-9];
NEW_STRING: (NEW_DIGIT+ | STRING_CHAR+ (NEW_DIGIT+)?);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!

That is what I thought, that my `STRING_CHAR` should be able to match the numbers too, but it doesn't.

It can parse letters (_"test"_), letters with numbers (_"test123"_), but when the only input is numbers without any letters (_"123"_), it does not work.

Any idea why?

Comment: Because then `NEW_DIGIT` can match the input too. And as I wrote in that case the first rule wins.